# How to access files from an Amazon S3 bucket without an account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This might be a stupid question, but I've never used AWS before.

So apparently, to create an AWS account I need to give my credit card information, but I don't want to do that.

Is there any other way to access the information from this link?:
https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/quizdb-public/?region=us-east-1&tab=overview

Comment: Normally, yes, you could use the aws cli without an account to access a public bucket.  That bucket, however, is not public, or at the least, it does not allow public access to list objects.

Comment: @AnonCoward oh really? The place where I got it from says it is public. I guess not.

Comment: This is not a public bucket. Where did you get the link from?

Comment: @BuhtanDingDing Correct.  The bucket is not public.  Perhaps it was once, but it no longer is.

Answer (score 1):

The URL https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/quizdb-public/?region=us-east-1&tab=overview

is the link that will be shown in the address bar when you log into the AWS console, go to S3 and click on the bucket. If you do not have access to that specific AWS account and the AWS console you will not be able to access the information in the bucket with that URL.